# PDF file upload works in Javascript AWS SDK v2 but doesn't work in AWS SDK v3

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My backend app is receiving a PDF file as a Blob.

My AWS SDK v3 code is the following:

```js
import {S3Client} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import {Upload} from "@aws-sdk/lib-storage";

const config = {
    region: awsRegion!,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: awsAccessKeyId!,
        secretAccessKey: awsSecretAccessKey!,
    },
}

const client = new S3Client(config);

            const params = {
                Key : 'filName.pdf',
                Body : f,
                Bucket : 'my.bucket',
                ContentType : 'application/pdf'
            }

            try {
                const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
                    client: client,
                    params: params,
                    leavePartsOnError: false,
                    queueSize: 4,
                    partSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 // 5 MB
                });

                parallelUploads3.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
                    console.log("progress")
                    console.log(progress)
                });

                const result = await parallelUploads3.done();
                console.log(result)
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("ERROR");
                console.error(e);
            }
```

The response I get is the following:

```
{
  $metadata: {
    httpStatusCode: 100,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Bucket: "my.bucket",
  Key: "filName.pdf",
  Location: "https://my.bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/filName.pdf"
}
```

So it seems OK, but when I go into S3, the file is not there.

If I use the AWS SDK v2, it does work, with pretty much equivalent code:

```js
            const s3 = new AWS.S3({
                region: awsRegion!
            });

            const params = {
                Key : 'filName.pdf',
                Body : Buffer.from(await body.file.arrayBuffer()),
                Bucket : 'my.bucket',
                ContentType : 'application/pdf'
            }


            s3.upload(params, function(err, response) {
                console.error(err)
                console.info(response)
            });
```

What's going wrong with the V3 SDK? Is that a bug or am I missing something?

EDIT: When I upload an image, say a PNG, the upload DOES work. It's when I try to upload a PDF that the file does not appear on S3.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to largely be the [documented example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-lib-storage/) of using Upload with lib-storage, except for one thing:  `client: new S3({}) || new S3Client({})`. Have you investigated using S3 rather than S3Client to see if that's somehow the cause?

Comment: Doesn't work either.

The thing is, the upload DOES WORK when I upload an image, say a PNG file, but DOES NOT work with a PDF.

This leads me to believe that it's something related to the file its self, maybe mime types, or something but I can't figure out what it is...

Comment: Regardless of content type (which would potentially impact how a client treats the file when downloading), the object should be there whether it's PNG or PDF. How are you verifying that the PNG is there but the PDF is not? Use ListObjectsV2 or HeadObject via the awscli or your preferred SDK.

Comment: I'm using the cloud console (browser)

Comment: The AWS example code works for me with both PNG and PDF files, as expected. You might want to enable SDK debugging to see what, if anything, you're missing.

Comment: A newer version of Bun and Elysia fixed this issue.

Comment: Interesting that the HTTP status code in the failing scenario was 100 which suggests that HTTP headers were sent to S3, S3 responded 100 Continue, but the client did not subsequently send the body. So the client never completed the upload and S3 never showed the object (because it was incomplete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newer version of Bun and Elysia fixed this issue.

Comment: exact version number please